# running order by and group by in objection js

Tags: mysql, objection.js

I want to add group by and order by in the same query, I have checked so many example where we can do this in mysql but how that will be done in objection. Currently I am doing this with foreach loop which is not good for large result.

```
logs = await logs.select('id','story_id').orderBy('id','desc'); 
                let ids:any[] = [];

                _.each(logs, (log:any)=>{
                    if(empty(ids[log.thred_id]))
                        ids[log.thred_id] = log.id;
                });

                log = await Logs.query().whereIn('id', _.values(ids)).orderBy('id','desc');
```

I want to show recent update of story only

Comment: Have you checked https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/find-methods.html#groupby ?

Comment: @Rashomon yes, I checked this but it gives first log by story_id not the last

Comment: Do you have the equivalent mysql query?

Comment: Do you have your schema available?

Comment: No, I don't have the schema yet,  thanks but solution is not needed now, i have done with this task :-)